# Printing a textarea element with text included

Tags: javascript, jquery, printing, textarea

I've seen a number of solutions to 'printing a div' or 'printing an area of a page' but not one that addresses the problem I'm having:
I've tried the following javascript function:

```
var mywindow = window.open('', 'my div', 'height=400,width=600');mywindow.document.write('<html><head><title>my div</title>');
mywindow.document.write('</head><body >');
mywindow.document.write($('.page').html());
mywindow.document.write('</body></html>');
mywindow.print();
mywindow.close();
```

And that displays all the page elements, but NOT any text input in the textarea elements.

Likewise I've used the printThis jQuery plugin:

```
$('.page').printThis();
```

But that, similarly, includes the bounding boxes of the textareas, but NOT any text that might be inside them.

Is there some way to ensure text in a textarea element is sent to the printer too?

Comment: fetch the value of the textarea and place that in body instead of adding the whole container. Hope this helps.

Comment: You can update a text area value using jQuery.